# Login with github get repositore private

Tags: ruby-on-rails, github

Hi I am doing a login with Github in rails 4, but I'm looking for ways to get private repositories and I can not get them, some help ?.

Comment: I am sure that you have read https://developer.github.com/v3/oauth/

Comment: please share what you have tried

Comment: Are you trying to create a private repo on github or access it?

Comment: How to request access to a private repository in github ?

Comment: @FelipeAntonioBarrios ask the user to grant you permission on access.. The owner of that private repo can allow access following these guidelines https://help.github.com/articles/adding-collaborators-to-a-personal-repository/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access a private repo created by someone else, the repo's creator should give you permission to view/clone/commit to it.

If you want to create a private repo yourself, [you should pay.](https://github.com/account/upgrade)